# Error in panel spatial model in R using spml

Tags: r, spatial

I am trying to fit a panel spatial model in R using the package spml. I first define the NxN weighting matrix as follows

```
neib <- dnearneigh(coordinates(coord), 0, 50, longlat = TRUE)
dlist <- nbdists(neib, coordinates(coord))
idlist <- lapply(dlist, function(x) 1/x)
w50 <- nb2listw(neib,zero.policy=TRUE, glist=idlist, style="W")
```

Thus I define two observations to be neighbours if they are distant within a range of 50km at most. The weights attached to each pairs of neighbour observations correspond to the inverse of their distance, so that closer neighbours receive higher weights. I also use the option zero.policy=TRUE so that observations which do not have neighbours are associated with a vector of zero weights.

Once I do this I try to fit the panel spatial model in the following way

```
mod <- spml(y ~  x  , data = data_p, listw = w50, na.action = na.fail, lag = F, spatial.error = "b", model = "within", effect = "twoways" ,zero.policy=TRUE)
```

but I get the following error and warning messages

> Error in lag.listw(listw, u) : Variable contains non-finite values In
>   addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the
>   first 50)
>
> Warning messages: 1: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :   argument is not
>   numeric or logical: returning NA
>
> ...
>
> 50: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :   argument is not numeric or
>   logical: returning NA

I believe this to be related to the non-neighbour observations. Can please anyone help me with this? Is there any way to deal with non-neighbour observations besides the zero.policy option?

Many many thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You should check two things:
1) Make sure that the weight matrix is row-normalized.
2) Treat properly if you have any NA values in the dataset and as well in the W matrix.